# box layout with overflow auto in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, boxlayout

I am having a weird bug in chrome but not firefox. I have created as simple an example as possible:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            display:-webkit-box;
            display:-moz-box;
            -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
            -moz-box-orient:vertical;
        }
        .scrollable
        {
            -webkit-box-flex:1;
            -moz-box-flex:1;
            overflow:auto;
            background-color:red;
            display:-webkit-box;
            display:-moz-box;
        }
        .fixed
        {
            background-color:blue;
        }
        button:hover
        {
            background-color:red;
            opacity:.2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed</h1>
    <button>Test</button>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <div>
        <h1>Scrollable</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices nulla nec nulla vehicula a condimentum enim suscipit. Morbi accumsan est eget elit aliquet dictum bibendum ligula feugiat. Nam gravida sagittis luctus. Vestibulum cursus leo eu velit fermentum a commodo dolor imperdiet. Fusce non libero nec nisi molestie auctor et in est. Ut ac nibh est, vitae posuere velit. Quisque vulputate mattis sapien, interdum imperdiet purus placerat ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus est erat, suscipit non sollicitudin eget, porta et sem. Suspendisse tempor ullamcorper tellus, sed luctus magna auctor et. Sed et enim vel dolor eleifend eleifend sollicitudin at velit. Phasellus ac enim turpis. Phasellus lobortis nisi et augue sodales non fringilla tellus rutrum. Cras pretium metus facilisis metus viverra et commodo sapien viverra. Donec purus tellus, adipiscing ultricies interdum sed, aliquam feugiat nunc.</p>
        <button>Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Essentially I am trying to create a layout with a fixed header at the top and a vertically scroll-able section below it that fills the full height of the window. This seems to work well in both chrome and firefox. The issue I am having in Chrome is that the hover effect on the buttons causes the pane to scroll back to the top. My guess is that the hover effect is causing the pain to lay itself out again and when it does that, it scrolls to the top.

Through other testing it seems to be caused by having a box layout element with overflow:auto on it.

Has anyone else experience this issue? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this differently or to fix it?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The full layout I am trying to make is:

```
|---------------------------|
| Main Header               |
|---------------------------|
| Content Header   | Side   |
|------------------| Bar    |
|                  |        |
| Content          |        |
|                  |        |
-----------------------------
```

I would like the "Content" and "Side Bar" to scroll independently. The "Content" should scroll both horizontally and vertically while the "Side Bar" should only scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is kind of spooky, but it seems that Google just released an update that fixes the problem. The flex box layout now works for my desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here did some CSS mods and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/VHKbp/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately my real use case is more complicated than the example I provided. I actually have two independent columns that need to scroll independently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that Dipak provided was a good solution unless there is a specific reason you'd rather have a scrollable div opposed to using the browser's native scroll.

The only other suggestion I would make to this is that you make sure that the scrollable div has a padding-top to it to make up for the space that's covered by the fixed header.

so something like this:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.scrollable-div {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

you'll probably need additional styles, but just be conscience of what you're covering up.  Also if you need the scrollable div to work in a context w/out using the fixed header you should do a padding on the body or create an empty "padding" div that can take up the space.  This way as your site evolves you won't have to worry about the individual element; every time you change the header, it will remain independent.

Just stuff to keep in mind :)

Comment: I prefer to have the div itself scroll instead of the native browser scroll but it isn't a requirement. The problem I have with the suggested solution is that I actually have to columns that need to independently scroll. (One has its own header and then there is a header above both of them.